# jQuery find id by CSS Class

Tags: jquery, css, dotnetnuke

I'm new to `jQuery`. I assume this was asked hundred of times, but I couldn't find an answer.

I have a page in `dotnetnuke` in which I know the `CSS Class` but I need the element `ID`.
In this case I know that there will be only one element with the `CSS Class`.
How do I find it in `jQuery`?

---

Edit:

I want to move all children of the element with class  `FloatingFrameLightBlue1` to be children of `PopupWrapper` that i created a line before. But the append doesn't seems to work. 
what I'm doing wrong.
the code I have:

```
.
.
jQuery("body").append("<div id='popupWrapper'></div>");

jQuery(".FloatingFrameLightBlue1").children().append("popupWrapper");
.
.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? You have an element with an ID, and there's only one element with that ID, and you'd like to know what class it has ?

Comment: @roasted I edited the question and added more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myID = $('.knownClass').attr('id');
```

This selects the element by the known class and results with the ID.

Check [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
alert($('.myclass').attr('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the ID attribute by selecting the class:

```
$('.name_of_the_class').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the DOM based solution (could be more efficient).

`var id = $('.className').get(0).id;`

Answer (score 0):

By using `$('.name_of_class').doSomething()`. If you want to select by ID, you can use `('#id').doSomething()`.

Any other attribute: `$('div[attribute="value"]').doSomething()`.

To return the ID, replace `.doSomething()` by `.attr('id')`.

Comment: so it seems that the problem is somewhere else. I edited and expanded my response, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.